# how Web.config inherits IIS configuration settings?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

working on a college project about web.config file.
wants to know about how IIS settings is known by web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a link that describes the diffrent inheritance from web.config to machine.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To be syntactically correct, the web.config does not "know" about IIS settings. It's actually the other way around. IIS "knows" what is in the web.config, and handles requests to the application accordingly.